# Math contest geometry proof problem 2

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Could someone help me with this?

Let A, B, C, D, L, M, N be distinct points in the plane such that A, B, C, D are the vertices of a square with sides AB, BC, CD, DA and L, M, N lie on the sides AB, CD, BC respectively. If M is the mid-point of CD, then show that △LMN is not an equilateral triangle.